# Use type member as self-type

Tags: scala, self-type, type-projection

I'm having a problem with a recursive self-type that should correspond to a type member:

```
trait Elem { me =>
  type Peer

  import me.{Peer => Peer0}

  type This <: Elem { type Peer = Peer0 }

  def mkCopy(): This
}
```

Now I want to define a convenient trait:

```
trait ImmutableImpl extends Elem {
  _ : This =>

  def mkCopy(): This = this
}
```

This doesn't work, because **"error: not found: type This"** :(

Next attempt:

```
trait ImmutableImpl[Repr] extends Elem {
  _ : Repr =>

  type This = Repr

  def mkCopy(): This = this
}
```

This fails with **"Error: overriding type This ... This has incompatible type"**.

I can do only this abomination:

```
trait ImmutableImpl[Peer0, Repr <: Elem { type Peer = Peer0 }] extends Elem {
  _ : Repr =>

  type Peer = Peer0
  type This = Repr

  override def mkCopy(): This = this
}

class IntElem extends ImmutableImpl[Int, IntElem]
```

In the real case I have more type members, so that makes this last approach useless, as it's much more boiler plate that implementing the `mkCopy` by hand each time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround is to relax the refinement on `This`, as it appears to not be required in my API in the end:

```
trait Elem { me =>
  type Peer

  // import me.{Peer => Peer0}

  type This <: Elem // { type Peer = Peer0 }

  def mkCopy(): This
}

trait ImmutableImpl[Repr <: Elem] extends Elem {
  _ : Repr =>

  override type This = Repr

  def mkCopy(): This = this
}

class IntElem extends ImmutableImpl[IntElem] {
  type Peer = Int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a type parameter would be better suited for this.

```
trait Elem[A] { me: A =>
    def mkCopy(): A = this
}

scala> class Z extends Elem[Z]

scala> (new Z).mkCopy()
res0: Z = Z@3003a3a3
```

I think the problem is that the type member is not in the scope of the self-type declaration, and the way you worked around that was by using a structural type bound with another trait. But why not cut out the middleman and just use the type parameter on `Elem` with a self-type requiring it be the same type as the parameter.

Comment: The problem is, it will become `Elem[S <: Sys[S], A[~ <: Sys[~]] <: Elem[~, A]]` in the end and I have to carry that baggage around in many places; this is in fact the original motivation for having type members. I'm releasing the constraint on the refinement of `Elem { ... }` now, that way I can have an `override type This = Repr` in the implementation trait, it seems, and I don't seem to be relying on that general refinement.